# Doesn't find my variables when running perl script with cron

Tags: linux, perl, debian

I'm facing a very strange problem.
I'm running a script on a Squeeze Server with perl 5.10.1 from backports running. When I run the script from the console, it works perfect.
But when I tried to run it with cron, it gives errors like the "my var, my var2, my var3, etc" are wrong. And also it says there's syntax error due a missing "(".
But if i run it from the console, it works.

Here the beginning of the script and what it complains.

```
##!/usr/lib/perl
#BACKUPPEITOR 2012
#IT DOES BACKUPS OF EVERTHING AND USE RSYNC 
#TO UPLOAD THEM TO HIDRIVE-STRATO
#AND KEEP YOU POSTED OF IF SOMETHING WENT WRONT
#Uses
#use strict;
#use warnings;
use Net::SMTP;
use POSIX 'strftime';
use MIME::Lite;

#Variables
my $seconds = strftime '%H:%M:%S-%d%m%y', localtime;
my $time = strftime '%H:%M:%S_-_%d_%m_%Y', localtime;
my $tLog = strftime '%d%m%Y', localtime;
my $foMy = "/home/backup/data/mysql/";
my $foPsql = "/home/backup/data/postgres/";
my $uMy = 'USER';
my $pMy = 'SECRET';
my @mysql_re = "";
my @psql_status ="";
my @esanum_re ="";
my $foEsanum = "/home/folder/";
my $fMy ="";
my $logF = "/home/backup/log/backuplog_$tLog.log";


#Set mail config
MIME::Lite->send('smtp','mail.mailserver.org', Timeout=>60,AuthUser=>'SECRET', AuthPass=>'SECRET');
```

and that what i receive when i ran it as cronjob in the log file:

```
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 9: use: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 10: use: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 11: use: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 14: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 15: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 16: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 17: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 18: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 19: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 20: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 21: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 22: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 23: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 24: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 25: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 26: my: not found
/home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: 30: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

You see? it cant found the my variables, why?
Now, perl -V and uname -a, to give all te info.

```
srv156:/usr/bin$ perl -V
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "es_ES.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 10 subversion 1) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=3.2.0-4-686-pae, archname=i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi
    uname='linux callisto 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 smp debian 3.2.32-1 i686 gnulinux '
    config_args='-Dusethreads -Duselargefiles -Dccflags=-DDEBIAN -Dcccdlflags=-fPIC -Darchname=i486-linux-gnu -Dprefix=/usr -Dprivlib=/usr/share/perl/5.10 -Darchlib=/usr/lib/perl/5.10 -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dvendorlib=/usr/share/perl5 -Dvendorarch=/usr/lib/perl5 -Dsiteprefix=/usr/local -Dsitelib=/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 -Dsitearch=/usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 -Dman1dir=/usr/share/man/man1 -Dman3dir=/usr/share/man/man3 -Dsiteman1dir=/usr/local/man/man1 -Dsiteman3dir=/usr/local/man/man3 -Dman1ext=1 -Dman3ext=3perl -Dpager=/usr/bin/sensible-pager -Uafs -Ud_csh -Ud_ualarm -Uusesfio -Uusenm -DDEBUGGING=-g -Doptimize=-O2 -Duseshrplib -Dlibperl=libperl.so.5.10.1 -Dd_dosuid -des'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=undef, use64bitall=undef, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
    optimize='-O2 -g',
    cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.4.5', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=1234
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=12
    ivtype='long', ivsize=4, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=4, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc', ldflags =' -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /lib /usr/lib /usr/lib64
    libs=-lgdbm -lgdbm_compat -ldb -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt
    perllibs=-ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt
    libc=/lib/libc-2.11.3.so, so=so, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.so.5.10.1
    gnulibc_version='2.11.3'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-Wl,-E'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC', lddlflags='-shared -O2 -g -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                        PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_MALLOC_WRAP USE_ITHREADS
                        USE_LARGE_FILES USE_PERLIO USE_REENTRANT_API
  Locally applied patches:
    DEBPKG:debian/arm_thread_stress_timeout - http://bugs.debian.org/501970 Raise the timeout of ext/threads/shared/t/stress.t to accommodate slower build hosts
    DEBPKG:debian/cpan_config_path - Set location of CPAN::Config to /etc/perl as /usr may not be writable.
    DEBPKG:debian/cpan_definstalldirs - Provide a sensible INSTALLDIRS default for modules installed from CPAN.
    DEBPKG:debian/db_file_ver - http://bugs.debian.org/340047 Remove overly restrictive DB_File version check.
    DEBPKG:debian/doc_info - Replace generic man(1) instructions with Debian-specific information.
    DEBPKG:debian/enc2xs_inc - http://bugs.debian.org/290336 Tweak enc2xs to follow symlinks and ignore missing @INC directories.
    DEBPKG:debian/errno_ver - http://bugs.debian.org/343351 Remove Errno version check due to upgrade problems with long-running processes.
    DEBPKG:debian/extutils_hacks - Various debian-specific ExtUtils changes
    DEBPKG:debian/fakeroot - Postpone LD_LIBRARY_PATH evaluation to the binary targets.
    DEBPKG:debian/instmodsh_doc - Debian policy doesn't install .packlist files for core or vendor.
    DEBPKG:debian/ld_run_path - Remove standard libs from LD_RUN_PATH as per Debian policy.
    DEBPKG:debian/libnet_config_path - Set location of libnet.cfg to /etc/perl/Net as /usr may not be writable.
    DEBPKG:debian/m68k_thread_stress - http://bugs.debian.org/495826 Disable some threads tests on m68k for now due to missing TLS.
    DEBPKG:debian/mod_paths - Tweak @INC ordering for Debian
    DEBPKG:debian/module_build_man_extensions - http://bugs.debian.org/479460 Adjust Module::Build manual page extensions for the Debian Perl policy
    DEBPKG:debian/perl_synopsis - http://bugs.debian.org/278323 Rearrange perl.pod
    DEBPKG:debian/prune_libs - http://bugs.debian.org/128355 Prune the list of libraries wanted to what we actually need.
    DEBPKG:debian/use_gdbm - Explicitly link against -lgdbm_compat in ODBM_File/NDBM_File. 
    DEBPKG:fixes/assorted_docs - http://bugs.debian.org/443733 [384f06a] Math::BigInt::CalcEmu documentation grammar fix
    DEBPKG:fixes/net_smtp_docs - http://bugs.debian.org/100195 [rt.cpan.org #36038] Document the Net::SMTP 'Port' option
    DEBPKG:fixes/processPL - http://bugs.debian.org/357264 [rt.cpan.org #17224] Always use PERLRUNINST when building perl modules.
    DEBPKG:debian/perlivp - http://bugs.debian.org/510895 Make perlivp skip include directories in /usr/local
    DEBPKG:fixes/pod2man-index-backslash - http://bugs.debian.org/521256 Escape backslashes in .IX entries
    DEBPKG:debian/disable-zlib-bundling - Disable zlib bundling in Compress::Raw::Zlib
    DEBPKG:fixes/kfreebsd_cppsymbols - http://bugs.debian.org/533098 [3b910a0] Add gcc predefined macros to $Config{cppsymbols} on GNU/kFreeBSD.
    DEBPKG:debian/cpanplus_definstalldirs - http://bugs.debian.org/533707 Configure CPANPLUS to use the site directories by default.
    DEBPKG:debian/cpanplus_config_path - Save local versions of CPANPLUS::Config::System into /etc/perl.
    DEBPKG:fixes/kfreebsd-filecopy-pipes - http://bugs.debian.org/537555 [16f708c] Fix File::Copy::copy with pipes on GNU/kFreeBSD
    DEBPKG:fixes/anon-tmpfile-dir - http://bugs.debian.org/528544 [perl #66452] Honor TMPDIR when open()ing an anonymous temporary file
    DEBPKG:fixes/abstract-sockets - http://bugs.debian.org/329291 [89904c0] Add support for Abstract namespace sockets.
    DEBPKG:fixes/hurd_cppsymbols - http://bugs.debian.org/544307 [eeb92b7] Add gcc predefined macros to $Config{cppsymbols} on GNU/Hurd.
    DEBPKG:fixes/autodie-flock - http://bugs.debian.org/543731 Allow for flock returning EAGAIN instead of EWOULDBLOCK on linux/parisc
    DEBPKG:fixes/archive-tar-instance-error - http://bugs.debian.org/539355 [rt.cpan.org #48879] Separate Archive::Tar instance error strings from each other
    DEBPKG:fixes/positive-gpos - http://bugs.debian.org/545234 [perl #69056] [c584a96] Fix \G crash on first match
    DEBPKG:debian/devel-ppport-ia64-optim - http://bugs.debian.org/548943 Work around an ICE on ia64
    DEBPKG:fixes/trie-logic-match - http://bugs.debian.org/552291 [perl #69973] [0abd0d7] Fix a DoS in Unicode processing [CVE-2009-3626]
    DEBPKG:fixes/hppa-thread-eagain - http://bugs.debian.org/554218 make the threads-shared test suite more robust, fixing failures on hppa
    DEBPKG:fixes/crash-on-undefined-destroy - http://bugs.debian.org/564074 [perl #71952] [1f15e67] Fix a NULL pointer dereference when looking for a DESTROY method
    DEBPKG:fixes/tainted-errno - http://bugs.debian.org/574129 [perl #61976] [be1cf43] fix an errno stringification bug in taint mode
    DEBPKG:fixes/safe-upgrade - http://bugs.debian.org/582978 Upgrade Safe.pm to 2.25, fixing CVE-2010-1974
    DEBPKG:fixes/tell-crash - http://bugs.debian.org/578577 [f4817f3] Fix a tell() crash on bad arguments.
    DEBPKG:fixes/format-write-crash - http://bugs.debian.org/579537 [perl #22977] [421f30e] Fix a crash in format/write
    DEBPKG:fixes/arm-alignment - http://bugs.debian.org/289884 [f1c7503] Prevent gcc from optimizing the alignment test away on armel
    DEBPKG:fixes/fcgi-test - Fix a failure in CGI/t/fast.t when FCGI is installed
    DEBPKG:fixes/hurd-ccflags - http://bugs.debian.org/587901 Make hints/gnu.sh append to $ccflags rather than overriding them
    DEBPKG:debian/squelch-locale-warnings - http://bugs.debian.org/508764 Squelch locale warnings in Debian package maintainer scripts
    DEBPKG:fixes/lc-numeric-docs - http://bugs.debian.org/379329 [perl #78452] [903eb63] LC_NUMERIC documentation fixes
    DEBPKG:fixes/lc-numeric-sprintf - http://bugs.debian.org/601549 [perl #78632] [b3fd614] Fix sprintf not to ignore LC_NUMERIC with constants
    DEBPKG:fixes/concat-stack-corruption - http://bugs.debian.org/596105 [perl #78674] [e3393f5] Fix stack pointer corruption in pp_concat() with 'use encoding'
    DEBPKG:fixes/cgi-multiline-header - http://bugs.debian.org/606995 [CVE-2010-2761 CVE-2010-4410 CVE-2010-4411] CGI.pm MIME boundary and multiline header vulnerabilities
    DEBPKG:fixes/casing-taint-cve-2011-1487 - http://bugs.debian.org/622817 [perl #87336] fix unwanted taint laundering in lc(), uc() et al.
    DEBPKG:fixes/safe-reval-rdo-cve-2010-1447 - [PATCH] Wrap by default coderefs returned by rdo and reval
    DEBPKG:fixes/encode-heap-overflow - [PATCH] Fix decode_xs n-byte heap-overflow security bug in
    DEBPKG:fixes/digest_eval_hole - Close the eval "require $module" security hole in
    DEBPKG:fixes/unregister_signal_handler - [PATCH] main: Unregister signal handler before destroying my_perl
    DEBPKG:fixes/CVE-2012-5195 - avoid calling memset with a negative count
    DEBPKG:fixes/CVE-2012-5526 - [PATCH 1/4] CR escaping for P3P header
    DEBPKG:fixes/storable-security-warning - [PATCH] add a note about security concerns in Storable
    DEBPKG:patchlevel - http://bugs.debian.org/567489 List packaged patches for 5.10.1-17squeeze4 in patchlevel.h
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Dec 11 2012 14:20:21
  @INC:
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.10
    /usr/share/perl/5.10
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    .
```

And uname -a

```
Linux srv156 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 11:00:33 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
enter code here
```

Comment: Thank to Moritz-Bunkus and @ruakh now its works, but give me a error more weird than the another, but i think its a problem from the server, because it told me the that when i run it: tail: /var/log/backupeitor.log: file truncated
    /bin/sh: /home/backup/scripts/backupeitor.pl: Permission denied. The file has 777 permissions and its been by root lauched.

Comment: That is a different problem and you should ask another question.

Answer (score 6):

The very first line tells the kernel which program to use for that file -- but only if it looks exactly like this:

```
#!/path/to/interpreter
```

If it does not, like in your case, then the shell will continue executing said file and interpret it as a shell script. It therefore thinks that `my` and `use` are programs to executes, fails to executes them and prints the errors you see.

If you run the script with `perl /path/to/your/script` instead of simply `/path/to/your/script` then the kernel is not involved and the first line may actually look different.

Answer (score 5):

It's trying to run your Perl script as a shell script, which means that it's not recognizing the first line of your file as a shebang.

To fix this, you need to change the first line of your script from this:

```
##!/usr/lib/perl
```

to this:

```
#!/usr/lib/perl
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the 1st line of your script

```
    ##!/usr/lib/perl
```

Should be **(replace /lib/ with /bin/)**

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
```

`/usr/lib/perl` usually is a directory. Resulting the perl script being run as a `sh` script. As `sh` don't understand perl syntax, throw you all the errors.